# Dynamically Return Stripe Order Amount

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, google-ads-api

I'm attempting to retrieve the total order amount on a Stripe charge. It's different for every order. I need this value for Google Ads Dynamic conversions. **My Question: How to I retrieve/return the order value after a payment?**

```
//Stripe Payment Backend

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
line_items: [
{
// Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
price: 'price_mypriceID',
quantity: 1,
},
],
mode: 'payment',
success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/dashboard?success=true`,
cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/dashboard?canceled=true`,
});

res.json({url: session.url}) 
});
```

This code runs on a successful payment, triggering a Google Ads Conversion.

```
if (location == "?success=true"){

window.gtag('config', 'AW-myaccount');
window.gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-myaccount',
'value': {needToReturnDynamicValueHere}, <--------- This 
'currency': 'USD'
});

}, [location])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly a year later I've figured this out:

On the success item below add `&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`

```
app.post('/create-checkout-payWithCourse', async (req, res) => {


    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [
            {
                price: 'price_ID',
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/?canceled=true`,
    });

    res.json({ url: session.url });
});
```

Then on your backend add a new route as shown below:

```
app.get('/retrieve-session', async (req, res) => {
    const { session_id } = req.query;

    try {
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session_id);
        res.json(session);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to retrieve session data from Stripe' });
    }
});
```

Then on the front end:

```
if (window.location.href.includes("success=true")) {

    const sessionID = getParameterByName('session_id');

    // Retrieve the session from your server
    const response = await fetch(`/retrieve-session?session_id=${sessionID}`);
    const sessionData = await response.json();


    if (sessionData) {
        console.log(sessionData); // Log the entire sessionData object to inspect its structure
    
        if (sessionData.amount_total) {
            const dynamicAmount = sessionData.amount_total / 100; // Convert amount from cents to dollars
    
            console.log(dynamicAmount);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stripe has a guide on how to customize the [Success Page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page) where they show how to retrieve the Checkout Session server-side.  You can also get the [related Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_intent) where you can see the [amount charged](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-amount).

You can keep this to a single API call by passing the `payment_intent` in the [Expand parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/expand)

If we take the code snippet in the "[Create the Success Page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#create-success-page)" section we can modify it to retrieve the amount from the Payment Intent.:

```js
app.get('/order/success', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
    req.query.session_id, 
    expand=['payment_intent']
  );
  const amount = session.payment_intent.amount
  res.send() // return order amount here.
});
```

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: Updated to show how you would retrieve this server-side.